# CakePHP SMTPTransport keep alive option?

Tags: php, email, cakephp, smtp

is there a option for CakePHP SMTPTransport to keep alive the connection?
I send mass mails by using the SMTPTransport and a smtp server.
After a lot of mails the smtp server refused the connection with the error message:

```
SMTP Error: 454 4.7.0 Too many login attempts, please try again later.
```

I looked at the code of the SmtpTransport class and the send function. This function connect, auth, sends and disconnect for every send request. Is it possible to keep the connect alive?

send function of SmtpTransport.php:

```
public function send(CakeEmail $email) {
    $this->_cakeEmail = $email;

    $this->_connect();
    $this->_auth();
    $this->_sendRcpt();
    $this->_sendData();
    $this->_disconnect();

    return $this->_content;
}
```

Version: 2.4.1

Comment: It's not supported out of the box, you'll need to implement this functionality in a [custom/extended transport](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#creating-custom-transports). ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I have thought about something like this and have implemented a extended CakeMail and SmtpTransport and a new key in the email config "smtpKeepAlive". If the key is set to true the SmtpTransport won't connect, auth and disconnect on every method call. After sending all mails I can call a new disconnect method.

In my opinion it make sense to keep the connection alive as default and only have a method to close the connect if necessary. So the zend framework do.

Comment: I was struggling with this before, guess I should have issued a feature request... While it's pretty easy to implement, I find it kinda ugly that I also have to create an extended `CakeEmail` class that keeps the transport instance between resets. I don't think making connections persistent as a default is really necessary, but it would be nice to have an option, and further decoupling so that maybe the transports could easily be used directly would also be neat.